# springboot endpoint async response

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous

I am working on a springboot REST API.
I have one endpoint whih is in charge of doing several treatments.
I would like that each time a treatment is done it return it back right away to the caller.
so it will not wait that the entire treatments are done before returning a result.
@async is not exactly what I want because it will run a new thread for the whole endpoint and will return a result when all treatments will be done.
Even, I tried a threadPoolExecutor and I used one thread by treatment but also I cannot return each thread result right away. I have to wait that all threads end before returning the result.
So is there away that will take care of each treatment and return it own result right away when it is done?

Comment: The HTTP protocol used with REST API forces you to send one response message foreach one request message. As I understood you want to send the response in severeal parts, which is not possible out of the box.
You might think about splitting the processing into more than one request, like /startProcessing which returns an unique id, and /getPartialResult which is called with the previous Id, and returns the next part of the results.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your architecture you have a few option:

- you would send the request as it is now; on the backend side you would generate a new id for the request, and send back that id to the client. Now the client could subscribe to the websocket and wait for the backend to push the id related result to the websocket.
- you could use a messaging solution which would be similar to the previous one, but with Kafka, RabbitMQ, ...
- you could implement a polling mechanism between the two side: you would return an id like in the previous options and the client would check the status of the request with the id periodically from the backend. When the status is completed, it could fetch the result from another endpoint using the id.